# Computer RAM crashes, TV monitor not connecting

Tags: windows, memory, display, crash, tv

I've had this computer since June 2011 (nearly 1.5 yrs now?) and I've been having some really weird issues lately.

About 2 months back, while browsing the internet, my cursor would randomly freeze and get warped and yellow, freezing the computer every 5-20 seconds until I restarted it.
(I have pics of the mouse pointer if needed)
This problem would only happen ~once a week, so I had attributed it to just windows degrading or something similar to that.

A bit later, it started complaining about my paging file. I can't remember what it was exactly, but it would create a new one every 10-15 restarts, and give me notice.
I went through the standard procedure for fixing paging file issues, but I still have it to this day.
A little while after, my C:/ drive started getting full.
With 512gbs of storage, it got cluttered by fraps videos, and I left it like that for quite a while, not knowing that it was the fraps videos.

Now here's the kicker: Half my RAM stopped working!

My computer started giving me "Your computer is low on memory, please close -game I'm currently playing- to prevent a crash"

I ignored it at first, until my computer crashed. Oh joy.
Ran a virus scan, nothing found.

I then looked at the windows summary screen, and it told me that only 3.99gbs out of my 8 total were useable.

So something cut my RAM in half.

My friend who knows everything, and was trying to help me with my previous issues with no dice, suggested I use something to find out what was cluttering my harddrive, and it showed me to the fraps folder, after which I deleted 125 GBs' worth of data.

Now, my RAM is still crippled. For some reason that is confusing to me, my laptop with 4gbs of RAM can play games that my crippled tower crashed with.

So, my friend told me stuff about RAM, why it stops working etc. He said it could be because it's overclocked. (note: store did the overclocking)

I have not tried to jiggle the RAM around yet.

After every time my computer crashed because it ran out of RAM, or after I restarted it after the mouse issue, it would turn on, but the TV which I use for a monitor would not recognize it, so I would have to press the power button to turn it off and restart it again.

Now, after my latest crash when I tried to play a PS2 game that I assumed it would handle, I can't use it anymore. The TV refuses to recognize the computer. I've tried messing with channels, jiggling around with the cable, nothing works.

I can now not use my computer.

(I haven't tried a different monitor/TV, and I'm running windows 7)

I can get the exact specs through TeamViewer, using my laptop. I can also use it to remotely run the computer as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened to your RAM -- could be a separate issue -- but the mouse cursor issue, crashes, and now no video points to the video card, not the RAM. If you were having RAM issues, your computer would crash while you're using it via TeamViewer too, not only when you're directly connected to its display.

I have seen symptoms like this in the past with other video cards, where the GPU gradually degrades and becomes less capable over time, crashing in more and more scenarios, until it just gives up the ghost entirely. Your RAM disappearance could be software-related; it doesn't have any necessary correlation to the video problem.

Also, assuming any of your stuff is covered by a 2+ year warranty, the warranty is probably void because you (or the store, doesn't matter) overclocked stuff. You should avoid overclocking unless you really know what you're doing, and are able to regulate the temperature very well within the chassis using water cooling or over-spec fans or the like. Overclocking can reduce the lifespan of hardware even if it appears to "work" at first. It'd be like if your heart rate is 150 beats per minute all the time -- you probably wouldn't live past 30 or 40 years of age due to wearing out faster. The same thing happens with overclocking when you don't have proper cooling -- the core temperature of the video card rises, and this can lead to early failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very long so I didn't read all of it, that being said, if you're missing RAM then you may be using a 32bit OS(which in Windows limits you to 4GB max) or you need to remove the RAM and blow out any dust around the connector. The issue with using your TV as a monitor is probably caused by your GPU not outputing through that port, or your GPU simply failing to work. If you have a graphics card installed and use its video ports, then try using the dedicated video graphics ports which should be on the motherboard and see if it outputs. If so reinstall graphics drivers for your GPU, but considering the computer is 3 years old something might have damaged the GPU in that time. The easiest fix for all your issues is to get a new copy of 64bit Windows and do a full reinstall, assuming the issue is your graphics drivers this should allow you to cleanly reinstall them, and it should help with the issue of RAM, assuming it's a software issue. Or **take it back to whatever store you trusted to overclock it, and ask them to figure it out.**